# Android 4 ICS (AOSP) build error on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: android, build

I am trying to build **Android 4.0.1_r1** on Ubuntu 10.04 64bit. I have followed all the steps as mentioned in the [official build document](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) before I initiated "make -j2" for a "full engineering" lunch type.

After 2 hours of compilation , I got this error :-

> host Java: doclava (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: cts/tools/vm-tests-tf/src/dot/junit/opcodes/xor_long_2addr/Test_xor_long_2addr.java: trouble reading
>       at com.android.dx.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:87)
>       at util.build.BuildDalvikSuite.parseTestMethod(BuildDalvikSuite.java:588)
>       at util.build.BuildDalvikSuite.handleTests(BuildDalvikSuite.java:303)
>       at util.build.BuildDalvikSuite.compose(BuildDalvikSuite.java:159)
>       at util.build.BuildDalvikSuite.main(BuildDalvikSuite.java:131)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cts/tools/vm-tests-tf/src/dot/junit/opcodes/xor_long_2addr/Test_xor_long_2addr.java (Too many open files)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:120)
>       at com.android.dx.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:75)
>       ... 4 more
>   make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/vm-tests-tf_intermediates/tests] Error 1
>   make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>   Note: external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Stubs.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

After this above error , the build stops.

Modifications I did before the build are as follows :-

1. From /devices folder I removed Google , Samsung and Ti folder so that they are not included in the build.
2. In the /build/target/product/core.mk I removed the following apps -  Browser, HTMLViewer, Contacts

Although I am a complete beginner in Android source development, I'm having this hunch that the modifications may not be the actual cause of the build failure and root cause lies somewhere else. I need some advice on this.